# Python encoding issue with pound symbol

Tags: python

I have a program that gets a string from the user. they type in "£" but some weird "tu`" text replaces the "£" when PRINT ing the string.

my app is a gui which takes input from user, what could be the problem

Comment: Extended ASCII issue? your parser might only use 7 bit ASCII .

Comment: Are you printing the `"£"` string in the console or are you displaying it in your GUI? What GUI library are you using? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: string ="£"
print string

Comment: But in that code, `"£"` is a literal string in your code, it's not user input!

Comment: £ is a user input from the gui application, but when this is processed its prints the undesired output

Answer (score 0):

You need to print it like this:

```
a=raw_input("Enter something: ")
print a.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: but my app is a gui which takes input from user, what could be the problem ? any idea?

Comment: @AjayGupta, you definitely should add this information to your question.

Comment: done, now any solution?

Comment: @AjayGupta, the same: check whether you're reading the value correctly and `encode` it.

Comment: @AjayGupta  Encoding. First line is direction but maybe your os or python or any one module using incompatible encoding.

Comment: which encoding should i use then?